# Defective keyboard on Toshiba laptop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate. It types letter `j` by itself; when I try to type something it types `jjjjjjj`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: "What can I do for it." - Replace the keyboard.  A good technician should be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is taking it to a repair center, especially if there is warranty period left on your laptop. But if you have do-it-yourself skills and have no qualms about opening the belly of your laptop, check the following:

1. Make sure all contacts between the key, spring and circuitry is clean, especially in the case of the "J" key. If your laptop is using a loose type cover, you might even be able to clean its keyboard with gentle application of a compressed air spray through the slits between keys.
2. Use an ohmmeter to check the circuitry of the "J" key. You might not be able to fix any damage to circuits but I very much doubt such a thing has come to pass, as it would affect more than just one key.

**But first and most importantly** get a disc or USB flash drive containing another OS (say a Linux, Windows PE or Windows Setup) and test the key in another OS. I will be very much surprised to see that you failed to reproduce the issue, but do it nonetheless. Better sure than sorry.